# The service endpoint failed to listen on the URI '{0}' because access was denied

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting following error while running my wcf service

> *The service endpoint failed to listen on the URI '{0}' because access was denied. Verify that the current user is granted access in the
>   appropriate allowAccounts section of SMSvcHost.exe.config*

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Open the configuration file.

Add the user(s) to the ACCEPT list in the allowaccounts section of the config file.

Answer (score 0):

I got fix thanks for your reply.

Here is the fix

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joncole/archive/2010/06/10/tcp-port-sharing-access-is-denied.aspx